# Yii CDbHttpSession blob to php array

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am using CDbHttpSession for storing data into session. Ideally I am not suppose to read directly from data column from database table but I have to do it for some reason. What I am getting is a BLOB string like below

```
user_id|s:1:"3";role|s:7:"admin";role_level|s:1:"2";f0d337b53327bb94792bef26c6f44feb__id|s:1:"3";f0d337b53327bb94792bef26c6f44feb__name|a:2:{s:10:"first_name";s:5:"XYZ";s:9:"last_name";s:4:"PQR";}f0d337b53327bb94792bef26c6f44feb__states|a:0:{}test|s:11:"Its working";
```

Can anyone guide me to convert that into array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `unserialize()` to get PHP value from a stored representation.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: I tried this dude but its not working it gives me error:unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 272 bytes